# ERROR 1168 (HY000) Mysql Merge does not work

Tags: mysql

When I was creating merging table I have got this error. 
ERROR 1168 (HY000): Unable to open underlying table which is differently defined or of non-MyISAM type or doesn't exist

my query is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_001`(
    `sequence_id` BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `wb_id` BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `containerid` BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `screen_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `verified` TINYINT NOT NULL,
    `v_reason` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `v_type` TINYINT NOT NULL,
    `is_member` TINYINT NOT NULL,
    `gender` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
    `statuses_count` SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `description_length` SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    `fans_num` int NOT NULL,
    `follow_num` int NOT NULL,
    `last_update` INT NOT NULL default 0,
    `last_check` INT NOT NULL default 0,
    `is_crawled` TINYINT NOT NULL default 0,
    `info` varchar(512) NOT NULL default "", 
    INDEX (wb_id),
    INDEX (containerid),
    INDEX (statuses_count),
    INDEX (last_update),
    INDEX (last_check)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE users_002 LIKE users_001;
CREATE TABLE users_003 LIKE users_001;
CREATE TABLE users_004 LIKE users_001;
CREATE TABLE users_005 LIKE users_001;
CREATE TABLE users_006 LIKE users_001;
```

Then Merge:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `sequence_id` BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `wb_id` BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `containerid` BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `screen_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `verified` TINYINT NOT NULL,
    `v_reason` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `v_type` TINYINT NOT NULL,
    `is_member` TINYINT NOT NULL,
    `gender` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
    `statuses_count` SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `description_length` SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    `fans_num` int NOT NULL,
    `follow_num` int NOT NULL,
    `last_update` INT NOT NULL default 0,
    `last_check` INT NOT NULL default 0,
    `is_crawled` TINYINT NOT NULL default 0,
    `info` varchar(512) NOT NULL default "",
    INDEX (wb_id),
    INDEX (containerid),
    INDEX (statuses_count),
    INDEX (last_update),
    INDEX (last_check)
) ENGINE=MERGE UNION=(users_001,users_002,users_003,users_004,users_005,users_006) INSERT_METHOD=LAST;
```

Then I get when use "check table users;"

```
+-------------------+-------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table             | Op    | Msg_type | Msg_text                                                                                            |
+-------------------+-------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| weibo_miner.users | check | Error    | Table 'weibo_miner.users_001' is differently defined or of non-MyISAM type or doesn't exist         |
| weibo_miner.users | check | Error    | Unable to open underlying table which is differently defined or of non-MyISAM type or doesn't exist |
| weibo_miner.users | check | error    | Corrupt                                                                                             |
+-------------------+-------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How does this happen?
I have tried adding index for both merge table and normal table and deleting default value. None works out.
Also with union=(users_001) will give this

```
ERROR 1168 (HY000): Unable to open underlying table which is differently defined or of non-MyISAM type or doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have had a work around as :

```
create table users like users_001;
alter table users engine=merge union=(users_001,users_002...) insert_method=last;
```

This will create the merge table without error, yet I don't know why the problem in question happens.

Comment: Today, more than seven years later, I faced the same problem with MariaDB and this workaround saved me.

Answer (score 1):

```
 'alter table `tablename` engine=myisam;'
```

i met this problem either.well,finially found my way to solve it and hope it may be helpful to you to solve your problem.To solve it i dropped the union table and then, alter all the tables' engine for union to "myisam" ;

then create your union table as your way.look yixia.smile~

> smile~